# Veracode Issue : Improper Output Neutralization for Logs

Tags: logging, veracode

```
LOGGER.debug("response" + SecurityUtils.htmlEscape(result.toString()));
```

> Veracode Issue: Improper Output Neutralization for Logs

Why veracode still detects a bug in the above line?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the loggers where we are logging unnecessary request and response.

And for Other loggers statements: Issue fixed , instead of encoding the value, we have used ESAPI logger to log statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax:

LOGGER.debug("response" + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(result)));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).